# Change format of script list in Chrome dev tools?

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-devtools

Is there a way to change the grouping/ordering of the scripts in the Chrome developer tools?

I love this tool but this list format is the worst for editing.  I have files with the same name(typical for ExtJs OO development), and trying to search and open one up for debugging is tiresome.

It would be nice if the js files would be listed ungrouped, in alphabetic order by filename, but also displaying the path name.

I figure this might not be possible, and the only suggestion will be to post a bug to google.  But I figured its worth a shot!

Comment: **Ctrl** + **O** in the Scripts panel will give you the "Open File" dialog but it will not list the full path. File a feature request at http://new.crbug.com

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As Alexander mentioned, <kbd>Ctrl + O</kbd> in the Scripts panel will give you the "Open File" dialog but it will not list the full path. You can file a feature request at new.crbug.com

It's also worth nothing that Chrome 19 just came out with a new script navigator that should display things better for you:

[image]

Comment: Yeah, I've just noticed a nice little button at the top left of script pane. Googled to see when it was implemented and got here. Thanks for nice tools guys :D

Comment: In the new scripts panel you can also start typing the name and it will jump to the file but still the open file dialog (ctrl+o) with path would be better...